# Coldfusion CFMAIL & CfMailPart Custom Tags

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I am writing a custom tag for CFMAIL.  I need to handle certain emails differently then the standard CFMAIL.  I am using the following post as a staring point - http://www.cfhero.com/2011/11/creating-environment-safe-wrapper-for.html

Before

```
<cfmail to="no@example.com" from="no@test.com" subject="This is only a test">
<cfmailparam name="Importance" value="high">
hello world</cfmail>
```

After Custom Tags

```
<cf_email to="no@example.com" from="no@test.com" subject="This is only a test">
<cf_emailparam name="Importance" value="high">
hello world</cf_email>
```

Everything working correctly for the custom CFMAIL and CFMAILPARAM but my question is how to handle "CFMAILPART".  When using the existing CFMAILPART within the new tags, CF throws an error.

```
<cf_email to="no@example.com" from="no@test.com" subject="This is only a test">
<cf_emailparam name="Importance" value="high">
    <cfmailpart type="text">Text</cfmailpart>
    <cfmailpart type="html">HTML</cfmailpart></cf_email>
```

> Detail: The tag must be nested inside a cfmail tag.
>
> Message: Context validation error for tag cfmailpart.

I am striking out with my ideas and I am failing finding any help docs. Any help or starting points would most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you on? I am seeing that the code is from 2011. This person might have been doing this on CF 9

Comment: What is the use case for writing a custom tag for `cfmail`? It doesn't seem like you are really doing anything different.

Comment: Just say no to custom tags.

Comment: I am using a custom tag point some CFMAIL to a 3rd party to handle click rates, drops and such.  We have have dozens + of instances of CFMAIL,  The plan is to move a few to the 3rd party now, then eventually move some more.  Not all CFMAIL will be pointed at the 3rd party, that is why I want to use CFMAIL and a CF_EMAIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: While this will get it to work using custom tags, John Whish's solution using a cfc is more flexible.

You'll probably need to create a `cf_emailpart` custom tag for the same reason you created a `cf_emailparam` tag. `cfemailparam` must be contained in a `cfmail` tag

```
<cf_email to="no@example.com" from="no@test.com" subject="This is only a test">
    <cf_emailparam name="Importance" value="high">
    <cf_emailpart type="text">Text</cf_emailpart>
    <cf_emailpart type="html">HTML</cf_emailpart>
</cf_email>
```

**cf_emailpart**

Almost the Same as `cf_emailparam`. The last part of this associates the tag with cf_email

```
<cfif CompareNoCase(thisTag.hasEndtag,"YES") EQ 0 AND CompareNoCase(thisTag.executionMode,"END") EQ 0 >
    <cfexit method="exittag" />
</cfif>

<cfassociate basetag="cf_email" datacollection="emailPart">
```

Then you'll need to add this inside your `cf_email` custom tag file, after the section where you output the `cfmailparam` tags, and inside the `cfmail` tag.

```
<cfif isDefined("thisTag.emailPart")>
    <cfloop array="#thisTag.emailPart#" index="attrCol">
        <cfmailpart attributecollection="#attrCol#" >
    </cfloop> 
 </cfif>
```

I haven't tested this code, but I think this is the direction you'll have to go.

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be a custom tag? Seems to me this would be simpler wrapped up in a CFC. Something like:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <cffunction name="init" access="public" returntype="any" output="false">
        <cfreturn this>
    </cfunction>

    <cffunction name="sendEmail" access="public" returntype="void" output="false">
        <cfargument name="to" required="true">
        <cfargument name="from" required="true">
        <cfargument name="subject" required="true">
        <cfargument name="importance" required="true">
        <cfargument name="htmlContent" required="true">
        <cfargument name="textContent" required="true">

        <!--- do a check here to see if in production something like--->
        <cfif ListFirst(CGI.SERVER_NAME, ".") neq "www">
            <!--- override the to email address or whatever here --->
            <cfset to = "foo@development.local">
        </cfif>

        <cfmail to="#to#" from="#from#" subject="#subject#">
            <cfmailparam name="Importance" value="#importance#">
            <cfmailpart type="text/plain">#textContent#</cfmailpart>
            <cfmailpart type="text/html">#htmlContent#</cfmailpart>
        </cfmail>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Then you can call it via:

```
<cfset Mailer = new Path.To.Component()>
<cfset Mailer.sendEmail(
    to="foo@somewhere.com",
    from="bar@somewhere.com",,
    subject="An Email",
    importance="high",
    htmlContent="<p>Hello!</p>,
    textContent="Hello!"
)>
```

The Mailer instance can be a singleton (you only need one instance per application) and then you can do things like injecting a config setting into it if you want to instead of having the environment detection in the actual CFC.

Comment: I like this solution way better than even my own. cfcs are far more flexible than custom tags.

Comment: Not necessarily. CFCs and custom tags merely solve different problems. there are times when one is better suited than another. In this case, a CFC would be better.